# Динамический массив объектов класса

Tags: c++, массивы, ооп

Есть класс Person.Его наследуют классы Student и Teacher

Есть текстовый файл с которого считывает данные. Там где один это студент, где два это учитель.Цифра семь это мое количество человек(потом в цикле использую когда считываю инфу с файла)

```
7
1 Mike 17 PMI 89
1 Nick 19 PMI 67
2 John 29 English 7
2 Lee 45 Programming 20
1 Lina 21 PMP 71
2 Keyn 42 Math 12
2 Lee 45 History 20
```

Код в main() :

```
int n, type;
  ifstream in("Person.txt");
  in >> n;
  Person **arr = new Person*[n];

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {

    in >> type;
    switch (type)
    {

    case 1: arr[i] = new Student;  break;
    case 2: arr[i] = new Teacher; break;

    default: arr[i] = new Person;
      break;
    }
    arr[i]->input(in); //Вывожу на экран консоли то что в Person.txt


  }
```

С многомерными динамическими массивами знаком но не использовал с классами.
Не до конца понимаю что делает эта строчка Person `**arr = new Person*[n];`

```
new Person*[n] это я создаю новый объект класса персон или массив размером n ?Если массив то почему не тип int
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> что делает эта строчка Person **arr = new Person*[n];

Вы создаете массив указателей типа `Person`.

Comment: Ой, точно.Но тогда еще вопрос. arr[i] имеет тип Person. arr[i]=new Student/Teacher работает потому что Студент и Учитель наследуют Person?

Comment: @ZELIBOBA Не совсем. `arr[i]` имеет тип `Person*`. Переменной-указателю типа предка может быть присвоен адрес, где находится наследник.